# How can I plug my LPT printer into a motherboard with no parallel port?

Tags: usb, printer, port, parallel-port

I have a new computer with a **Asus P5QL Pro** motherboard and wanted to plug my old **HP DeskJet 950C** printer into it only to discover that the motherboard has **no** **LPT/Parallel** port.

What is the best solution for this?

- is there a **LPT-to-USB** adapter?
- do I need to buy an **LPT PCI** board?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A PCI card is the best option, PCI parallel port cards are cheap at around ~$15USD with a few higher-end models available too. There are also PCI Express parallel port cards, but for using with a standard desktop printer, I don't think there are any advantages when using PCIe. I could be wrong on this though.

Here are some Newegg links:
[PCIe to Parallel port cards](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=40000073%201187125705&Description=pci%20parallel%20port&name=PCI%20Express%20to%20Parallel%20Port)
[PCI to Parallel port cards](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=40000073%201187112435&Description=pci%20parallel%20port&name=PCI%20to%20Parallel%20Port%20Card)

Comment: "A PCI card is the best option," Why are those better options than a simple adapter?

Answer (score 7):

Belkin make a [USB Parallel Printer Adapter](http://catalog.belkin.com/IWCatProductPage.process?Product_Id=20651), but it is $39.99 which is a bit pricy. There is [this alternative](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0007UVRVO) on Amazon for $13.